# 2 BMT ejbs 1 single TX = impossible?

Tags: java, transactions, ejb, ejb-3.0, bean-managed-transactions

In brief, and with linking to [this topic](http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=16921):  **Is it possible** to have 2 EJBs having *Bean managed Transactions* nature in which the first EJB calls a method in the second one and all are wrapped in single `UserTransaction` that starts from the first EJB?

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17893144/2014619)

Comment: I'm seeking for a workaround this using BMT

Comment: No, this is not possible, which is the same answer as in the question you linked.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved through workaround like extending the `BMT`, the bean that you would like to inject, into a new class and annotate it as alternative bean and then inject the new annotated class into another `BMT`. It will work as a single transaction starting from `BMT` to the new annotated bean and ended by the caller `BMT`